Проблема SFML(Audio.hpp) & CMake
Есть проблема. Когда я подключаю SFML/Audio.hpp к своему проекту. Я получаю ошибку, мол система не может найти OpenAL32.dll. Я не могу понять почему .dll, если я линкую статические либы(она есть в папке lib, называется openal32.lib).
Вот так линкую
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)
set(CXX_STANDARD 17)

project ("Minesweeper")

set(SFML_DIR "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include/SFML-2.6.1/lib/cmake/SFML")
set(SFML_STATIC_LIBRARIES TRUE)
include_directories(${SFML_INCLUDE_DIR})
find_package(SFML 2.6.1 COMPONENTS system window graphics audio network OpenAL REQUIRED)

set(
        PROJECT_FILES
        "src/main.cpp"
        "src/game.cpp" 
        "src/game.h"
)

add_executable("Minesweeper" ${PROJECT_FILES})
target_link_libraries("Minesweeper" sfml-system sfml-window sfml-graphics sfml-audio sfml-network OpenAL)


¿Вы точно проверили, что openal32.lib является статической библиотекой?

Да, точно. Я задумываюсь может стоит линковать sfml-lib_name-s вместо sfml-lib_name
